# In Azure Function Java how do I set cookies using HttpResponseMessage

Tags: java, function, azure

In Azure Function Java how do I set cookies using HttpResponseMessage as I don't see any methods to support that in 2.0 version.

Comment: I know we may be able send using  return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).header("Set-Cookie", "session=" + sessionToken + "; Domain="+sessionCookieDomain+"; Secure; HttpOnly").build() ... but is there any other elegant way ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#write-functions-to-be-stateless), Functions should be stateless and idempotent if possible.

> Associate any required state information with your data. For example,
>   an order being processed would likely have an associated state member.
>   A function could process an order based on that state while the
>   function itself remains stateless.

By checking the [HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.httprequestmessage?view=azure-java-stable) and the [HttpRequestMessage.Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.httpresponsemessage.builder?view=azure-java-stable) interface, I am sorry that there is no direct method to set the cookie.

A workaround is to create your own MyHttpResponseMessage class which implements HttpResponseMessage interface.

Here is just a quick sample:

### HttpResponseMessageBuilder Class

```
public class HttpResponseMessageBuilder {

    HttpStatusType status; 
    Map<String,String> headers;
    Object body;

    private HttpResponseMessageBuilder(){};

    public static  HttpResponseMessageBuilder newResponseMessage(){
        return new HttpResponseMessageBuilder();
    }

    public HttpResponseMessageBuilder status(HttpStatusType type){
        status = type;
        return this;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessageBuilder header(String key, String value){
        if(headers == null) headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessageBuilder body(Object object){
        this.body = object;
        return this;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessageBuilder setCookie(String name,String value, String expire, String path, String domain, Boolean isSecure, Boolean isHttpOnly) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(name).append("=").append(value);
        if(expire != null)
            sb.append(";expires=").append(expire);

        if(path != null)
            sb.append(";path=").append(path);
        else
            sb.append(";path=").append("/");

        if(domain != null)
            sb.append(";domain=").append(domain);

        if(isSecure)
            sb.append(";Secure");

        if(isHttpOnly)
            sb.append(";HttpOnly");

        header("Set-Cookie", sb.toString());

        return this;
    } 

    public HttpResponseMessage build(){
        MyHttpResponseMessage myHttpResponseMessage = new MyHttpResponseMessage();
        if(status == null) status = HttpStatusType.custom(200);
        myHttpResponseMessage.setStatus(status);
        if(headers == null) headers = new HashMap<>();
        myHttpResponseMessage.setHeaders(headers);
        if(body == null) body = "";
        myHttpResponseMessage.setBody(body);
        return myHttpResponseMessage;
    }
}
```

### MyHttpResponseMessage Class

```
public class MyHttpResponseMessage implements HttpResponseMessage {

    HttpStatusType status; 
    Map<String,String> headers;
    Object body;

    @Override
    public HttpStatusType getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String key) {
        return headers.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    protected void setStatus(HttpStatusType status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    protected void setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    protected void setBody(Object body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Finally, you can use it in your function:

```
return HttpResponseMessageBuilder.newResponseMessage()
            .setCookie("SessionID", "1F5E409AE7020538130D15ACC54530F9", null, "/", ".domian.com", true, false)
            .body("123456789").build();
```